# bootstrap 3 checkbox is disabled in firefox firebug

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mozilla

I can't understand why my checkbox of bootstrap 3 is disabled in firefox firebug. I used the same code to add checkbox to my form before with same code.Here is my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
          <label>  
               <input type="checkbox"> Remember me  
          </label> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there any issue to solve the problem? or is any coding problem? Thanks

Comment: Creating a simple jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RK98m/ doesn't make the checkbox disabled. Maybe it is some JS code that does that. The checkbox on the page is also disabled, or only Firebug sees it as disabled?

Comment: there is no js error in firebug console

Comment: The checkbox appears disabled on the page?

Comment: checkbox is disabled only showing label

Comment: This is a Firefox only issue?

Comment: nope same problem in chrome

Comment: Perhaps it is a script that disables the checkbox. If you disable the JavaScript the issue remains?

Comment: disbles js cause no change

Comment: If you remove the bootstrap css the checkbox is not disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Hey finally i solved the issue. I used both bootstrap 3 and flat-ui so flat-ui disabled the check box. So i had to give display block in my css.